# Apache Syncope connected with LDAP doesn't update user

Tags: ldap, apache-syncope

I'm working with Apache Syncope 2.1.10 and I succesfully connect with LDAP server for user and group creation but when I try to update a field I get de following error in the update propagation task:

`[LDAP: error code 68 - Entry Already Exists]`

In the Mapping Rules I have the next ConnObjectLink:

`'cn='+cn+',ou=myCompany, DC=COM,DC=local'`

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's not relevant about ConnObjectLink. it may be related to push task.if you create a push task, syncope ask you Matching and Unmatching rules. you should choose uptade for matching rule and allow update. I found this document. May be that [documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SYNCOPE/Push) can help you.